# put regular expression in variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash, terminal

```
output=`grep -R -l "${images}" *`
new_output=`regex "slide[0-9]" $output`
```

Basically $output is a string like this:

slides/_rels/slide9.xml.rels

The number in $output will change. I want to grab "slide9" and put that in a variable. I was hoping new_output would do that but I get a command not found for using regex. Any other options? I'm using a bash shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Well, regex is not a program like grep. ;)

But you can use

```
 grep -Eo "(slide[0-9]+)"
```

as a simple approach. -o means: show only the matching part, -E means: extended regex (allows more sophisticated patterns).

Answer (score 0):

Reading *I want to grab "slide9" and put that in a variable.* I assume you want what matches your regexp to be the **only** thing put in `$new_output`? If so, then you can change that to:

```
new_output=`egrep -R -l "${images}" * | sed 's/.*\(slide[0-9]+\).*/\1/'`
```

Note no setting of `output=` is required (unless you use that for something else)
If you need `$output` to use elsewhere then instead use:

```
output=`grep -R -l "${images}" *`
new_output=`echo ${ouput} | sed 's/.*\(slide[0-9]+\).*/\1/'`
```

sed's s/// command is similar to perls s// command and has an equivalent in most languages.

Here I'm matching zero or more characters `.*` before and after your `slide[0-9]+` and then remembering (backrefrencing) the result `\( ... \)` in sed (the brackets may or may not need to be escaped depending on the version of sed).   We then replace that whole match (i.e the whole line) with `\1` which expands to the first captured result in this case your `slide[0-9]+` match.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations using awk is better :

```
output="`grep -R -l "main" codes`"
echo $output
tout=`echo $output | awk -F. '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(index($i,"/")>0){n=split($i,ar,"/");print ar[n];}}}'`
echo $tout
```

This prints the filename without the extension. If you want to grab only slide9 than use the solutions provided by others.

Sample output :

```
A@A-laptop ~ $ bash try.sh
codes/quicksort_iterative.cpp codes/graham_scan.cpp codes/a.out
quicksort_iterative graham_scan a
```